# 3D printing layer shift on power outage resume

Tags: creality-ender-3, layer-shifting

I have an Ender 3 pro. In my country electricity outage is an issue, though it comes back pretty instantaneously, when I hit the resume button on the Ender 3 pro after heating the hot end and the bed when the hot end lifts the Y-axis or X-axis shifts a little bit, I do not understand why as when there is no power outage the prints are just flawless.

I have also tried tightening everything but feels like the motors are having their own fun tilting an extra step for no reason. I have thrown away many prints because of this problem as I work in robotics and prototyping is a necessary thing for me and so is the accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on your exact firmware, but it could be that it is using a [M413 power loss recovery](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M413.html) rather than a power loss interrupt pin. Possible you might be able to change this with your current firmware, but worst case you could install a new controller that does support this power loss interrupt pin.

Depending on the frequency and duration of your power outages it may be worth getting an uninterruptible power supply (UPS). With the heat bed off [this UPS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000FBK3QK) would run a full print easily. It would even handle a heat bed for shorter outages.

Where you work in robotics, you are probably electrically savvy enough to set your printer up on [direct DC battery power](https://youtu.be/5uUb-VnTzlU?t=625), which would be cheaper than a UPS of equivalent energy storage. If you need help going that route just post over on electrical engineering stack exchange with the power supply info.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need a UPS with EMI filter. I had this same issue and I opt to a regular desktop UPS and the problem was still there. So, I connected a EMI filter and it worked.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you expand upon your answer and explain why the EMI filter was required? Also, for the uninitiated, maybe explain what an EMI filter is and how it helped.